# OAuthCallback error on Netlify using sidebase/nuxt-auth@0.5.0 when loging with Google/Facebook provider

Tags: netlify, nuxt3, nuxt-auth

After deploying my `Nuxt@3.5.3` application using `@sidebase/nuxt-auth@0.5.0` to Netlify I got the `OAuthCallback` error when trying to log in using Google/Facebook provider.

On localhost everything works fine.

The [documentation](https://sidebase.io/nuxt-auth/configuration/nuxt-config#origin) says: "You must set the origin in production!"

I'm using both options.

1. I have set `AUTH_ORIGIN` environment
2. and also `origin` key in `nuxt.config.ts` both to `https://example.com`.

Maybe the error is caused by something else but I don't know what can it be if the localhost app works fine.

Can somebody help?